# How about using multiple threads/process to make programs run faster in python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-asyncio

I'm currently developing a computer vision project using two cameras and I'd like to improve the speed of the program by using multiple threads, processes or asyncio, but my experience is limited and I don't know how to rewrite the architecture of the program, maybe you can give me some advice,

The program mainly uses tkinter opencv and numpy, Reads data from two cameras and then calculates a result based on the acquired data

here is the Minimum run example:

```
class gui():
    def __init__(self,args):
        some_layout...
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.get_data_from_Cam1()
        self.root.mainloop()


    def get_data_from_Cam1(self):
        ..read frame from cam 1..
        self.job = self.root.after(1, self.process_Cam1ata())

     def process_Cam1ata(self):
        ..process_Cam1ata ,You can assume it is an OCR operation..
        self.job = self.root.after(1, self.get_data_from_Cam2())

     def get_data_from_Cam2(self):
        ..read frame from cam 1..
        self.job = self.root.after(1, self.process_Cam2Data())

     def process_Cam2Data(self):
        ..process_Cam2ata.. #High computational capacity 
        self.job = self.root.after(1, self.show_result_on_gui())

     def show_result_on_gui(self):
        ..show result.. 
        self.job = self.root.after(1, self.get_data_from_Cam1())
```

Also I would like to ask if the 'after' function of tkinter is an asynchronous operation?

Comment: _"Also I would like to ask if the 'after' function of tkinter is an asynchronous operation?"_ `after` just places work to be done on a queue. The work eventually runs in the same thread as all of the other GUI code.

Comment: FWIW, your code isn't actually using `after` to any effect. `after(1, foo())` will run `foo()` immediately, and then pass the result to `after`.

Comment: if you need to do work that *does not block* the GUI, then you need to spawn a thread. threading involves communication between threads. that is best done with queues.

Comment: You really need processes  - NOT threads! - one per camera and one for the GUI. Interprocess communications requires care. I've not come across a queue for this that works. Sockets work _really_ well and are highly optimised.

Comment: @jwal Thank you very much for your suggestion, I tried Sockets and it really suits my work, very simple and elegant multi-process solution

Comment: @Amnesie pleased to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again to @jwal for the suggestion to use sockets.
I've rewritten the architecture of my code and the speed has really improved.

here is the Minimum run example:

```
import socket
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event

class Gui():
  #gui for show frame from client
  def __init__(self,args):
        some_layout...
      self.root = tk.Tk()
      while not self.StopEVENT.is_set():
          self.update_display()
          self.root.update()
          self.root.after(10)
  def update_display(self):
      # try to get frame from two Queues 


def get_data(c, addr, queue_list, StopEVENT):
  #Receive frame from client,will run in subprocess per camera

if __name__ == '__main__':
    StopEVENT = Event()
    s = socket.socket()  
    s.setblocking(False)
    s.bind((host, port))  
    print("Server ON")
    s.listen(5)

    cam1_que = Queue(maxsize=1)
    cam2_que = Queue(maxsize=1)
    queue_list = [cam1_que, cam2_que]
    gui_process = Process(target=Gui, args=(queue_list, StopEVENT))
    gui_process.start()
    process_pool = []
    client_timer = 0
    while True:
        try:
            clientSock, addr = s.accept()
        except BlockingIOError:
            continue
        p = Process(target=get_data, args=(clientSock, addr, queue_list, StopEVENT,))
        process_pool.append(p)
        p.start()
        client_timer += 1
        if client_timer == 2:
            print('All Client connected')
            break
    while not StopEVENT.is_set():
        pass
    s.close()
    gui_process.join()
    gui_process.close()

    for p in process_pool:
        p.kill()
    print('done')
```

I also tried replacing all `Process` by `threading.Thread` , also a multi-thread version , and it still runs well, but it is slightly slower.

This is my first attempt at using sockets and I'm glad it works, but there may be some details that could be optimised, and I'd appreciate some suggestions for improvements